# Modifier Keys get stuck on single or double tap

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, lenovo, tablet, synaptics

I have a Lenovo Miix 2 11" tablet/laptop that uses a Synaptics keyboard dock. I noticed that if I press and release any of the modifier keys, they will remain "on" until I press another key.

e.g. Press and release 'Shift'. Press and release 'K' key. "K" is typed out.

e.g. Double tap 'Shift'. Tap 'K'. It appears caps locks is on now?

These issues make coding a real frustration. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Start the `gnome-control-center` aka <kbd>Settings</kbd>**
2. **Select <kbd>Universal Access</kbd>**

   [image]
3. **Click <kbd>Typing Assist (AccessX)</kbd> in the <kbd>Typing</kbd> section.**

   [image]
4. **Switch <kbd>Sticky Keys</kbd> to <kbd>OFF</kbd>.**

   [image]

Comment: Strange how they would have that enabled by default.

Comment: I can not say unfortunately.

Comment: I should have thought of this myself...  **;-)**

Comment: They can have been enabled if you press `shift` five time in a row.